# Trying to get rid of the '0' after each output utilizing a function, but unsure of what I could return

Tags: c++, function, return

[Pastebin Code](https://pastebin.com/hBu7Mq28)

```
int gradeCalculation(int grade, int topGrade)
{
    if (grade >= topGrade - 10)
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    else if (grade >= topGrade - 20)
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    else if (grade >= topGrade - 30)
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    else if (grade >= topGrade - 30)
        std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "F" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Programming Problem I'm Solving](https://imgur.com/a/7ge6g)

After each output is a '0' from the return. I've tried to use a void function, but my compiler threw an [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOwJO.jpg) Any ideas on what could be wrong with my code. Everything works fine as it is, but it's that tiny detail.

Comment: My crystal ball says that in the rest of your code you are writing `cout << gradeCalculation(x,y)`

Comment: When you used a void function were you still returning a value? You can't do this.

Comment: You need to show the code that is calling `gradeCalculation`.

Comment: Why you don't like "D"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the char corresponding to the grade instead of calling  `cout << .. endl` (because this only displays things, it does not return values). So when you make calls to `gradeCalculation` you get the char and you're able to display it.

```
char gradeCalculation(int grade, int topGrade)
{
    if (grade >= topGrade - 10)
        return 'A';
    else if (grade >= topGrade - 20)
        return 'B';
    else if (grade >= topGrade - 30)
        return 'C';
    else if (grade >= topGrade - 30)
        return 'D';
    else
        return 'F';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `std::cout << "Student " << i << " score is " << scoreArray[i] << " and their grade is " << gradeCalculation(scoreArray[i], highestGrade) << std::endl;` implies that gradeCalculation has a return value. If you want to make gradeCalculation a void function it must be called separately from the `std::cout` statement.

Answer (score -2):

I think you use the function in a statement like 
cout << gradeCaculation(int a, int b);
Instead use just 
gradeCalculation(int a, int b);

Comment: You should edit your original answer rather than posting 2 answers. You also should not duplicate answers.